# How do I prevent a dynamic link change in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I develop in ASP.NET MVC so please forgive my lack of the basics when it comes to PHP and WordPress.  We have a WordPress site where the terms and conditions link in the footer is broke on one page but works on another.

On our home page (http://www.ourdomain.com) there is a link and when I hover on it I can see in Chrome that it dynamically changes from:

ourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/mm/pdf/Terms.pdf

to:

www.ourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/mm/pdf/Terms.pdf

When I view the source of the page the anchor tag is like this:

```
<a href="wp-content/themes/mm/pdf/Terms.pdf">Terms</a>
```

This works fine and renders the necessary pdf file.  We have another url (http://www.ourdomain.com/contact) that also has a terms and conditions link that changes from:

ourdomain.com/contact/wp-content/themes/mm/pdf/Terms.pdf

to:

www.ourdomain.com/contact/wp-content/themes/mm/pdf/Terms.pdf

When I view the source of the page the anchor tag is as follows:

```
<a href="wp-content/themes/mm/pdf/Terms.pdf">Terms</a>
```

I have access to the entire site and the MySQL database for the site.  What can I change to prevent the link from adding **content** to the URL?  Are such links usually stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you didn't enter full path so the address is countine from your page address. as you see happend with the **contact**

**/** will point to domain base

**./** or **empty** will point to current url

Examples example.com/contact

```
<a href="/somefolder/file.pdf">
```

will point to http://example.com/somefolder/file.pdf

```
<a href="./somefolder/file.pdf">
```

will point to http://example.com/contact/somefolder/file.pdf

To avoid this you can enter the full url.

In case of wordpress if the link is in your theme you can use the function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to get the full url for your theme.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/pdf/Terms.pdf">Terms</a>
```